# Moodle external database login fails

Tags: php, moodle

I have been trying this for external moodle login

```
   <?php
require('config.php');
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$dashboard = $CFG->wwwroot;
$user = authenticate_user_login($name, $password);
if(complete_user_login($user))
{
echo "login";
}
else
{
   echo "not login";
}
?>
```

But this throws me some errors in a error page if the user or password is invalid.
is there anyway that I can get the error as variable so that I can handle in code. The following function is doing that

```
$user = authenticate_user_login($name, $password);
```

Comment: Your PHP error log *might* contain more information.  Best of luck... Moodle is a real pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable by reference and it will store the reason for the error.

```
$failurereason = '';
authenticate_user_login($name, $password, false, $failurereason);
```

the value will be one of these

```
/** Can not login because user does not exist. */
define('AUTH_LOGIN_NOUSER', 1);

/** Can not login because user is suspended. */
define('AUTH_LOGIN_SUSPENDED', 2);

/** Can not login, most probably password did not match. */
define('AUTH_LOGIN_FAILED', 3);

/** Can not login because user is locked out. */
define('AUTH_LOGIN_LOCKOUT', 4);
```